# How to edit an on line PDF/A form?

Tags: pdf

I want to edit an online form and print it. I clicked on enable editing and I got a message that if I do it won't be compatible with a PDF/A file. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it, it probably does not matter. That message is relevant only if you plan to keep the edited PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

For printing no.

PDF/A and it's variants are standardized versions used for archiving documents. Libraries, etc use them to make sure files they put into archives do not include materials that they don't need / want / support (videos, for example). What, depends on the version.

So if you're enabling editing just for printing and not saving the document back (without proper PDF/A compatibility and checking), you can ignore the warning.